# Gmail App on iPhone 4S doesn't complete entire "Push" of email

Tags: iphone, applications, gmail

So the Gmail app on my iPhone 4S notifies me with a badge that says I have 1,2,3...n unread messages.  In true push format, when an email is sent to the account it notifies me fairly quickly, but when I click into the app it still has to download them so it's a bit of a pain to have to wait the 2-10 more seconds to able to READ the actual email.

Is this the way it's designed or is there a setting I'm forgetting about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it was designed that way.

The only notification are the badge and the sound.

---

But only Mail can push notify you **and** download the message in the background. For App Store app, you'll have to open them for the mail to be downloaded.